# php regex match everything before last slash except trailing slash

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex to match everything before the last slash, while excluding a possible trailing slash.

```
/part1/part2/part3        should match /part1/part2
/part1/part2              should match /part1
/part1/part2/part3/       should match /part1/part2
/part1/part2/             should match /part1
```

So far I've come up with this: https://regex101.com/r/pKhYQU/1 but this still includes a trailing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `preg_match`, use a lookahead assertion `(?=/.)` (that means *followed by* and that isn't a part of the whole match, it's only a test):

```
~.*(?=/.)~
```

or

```
~.*(?=/[^/])~
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/pKhYQU/3)

With `preg_replace`:

```
echo preg_replace('~/[^/]*/?$~', '', $path);
```

You can also use `explode`, remove the last item and then `implode`:

```
$parts = explode('/', rtrim('/part1/part2/part3/', '/'));
array_pop($parts);
echo implode('/', $parts);
```

Comment: The last 2 matches are still wrong. I know I can do it with an explode, but if I use an explode there's no point in using a regex.

Comment: @SheperdOfFire - The artisan must decide whether to use a hammer, or a screwdriver to get that part of the task done.   Use the right tool for the right job.  :)

Comment: @KraangPrime, I know, that's why I'd like to do all in a single regex